# FileNotFoundError: File b'tek0000ALL.csv' does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando ller un archivo .csv y me da el siguiente error:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'tek0000ALL.csv' does not exist

El archivo está en el mismo dirtectorio que el programa y el nombre está bien copiado. El código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as ss

df = pd.read_csv("tek0000ALL.csv")
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar fallando?

Comment: ¿Estás usando Windows? Vigila que no tengas las extensiones de archivo ocultas en el explorador y tu csv se llame en realidad "tek0000ALL.csv.csv" o "tek0000ALL.csv.txt" Puedes listar el contenido de tu directorio actual haciendo en tu script `import os; print(os.listdir())` y comprobar si de verdad el nombre es correcto,

Comment: Prueba a poner la ruta absoluta del fichero para probar.

Comment: @FJSevilla Uso Win7. Las extensiones no están ocultas. He ejecutado el comando que indicas y de entre todo lo que sale, aparece un archivo que sí está en la misma carpeta y otro que está en otra. Pero no salen todos los archivos. Tengo varias ventanas abiertas con scripts que están en diferentes directorios.

Comment: @IkerEtxebarria Efectivamente, poniendo toda la ruta (y modificando "\" por "/") se soluciona el problema.

Comment: Si la ruta absoluta funciona significa que tu directorio de trabajo en el momento en el que intentas abrir el archivo no es el mismo que el de este script. Con el código que expones, ejecutado como módulo principal y con el archivo en el mismo directorio no hay forma de reproducir el problema, algo más debe estar ocurriendo aparte de lo mostrado para que el este error tenga lugar. Por ejemplo, si este script es importado por el script principal la ruta de trabajo es la del script principal y por tanto el fichero debería estar en su directorio, no en el de este script.